# Get textbox value from Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, interop

A user has provided me with an Excel document that has textboxes in a few of the cells.  I have the usual setup code to load the Excel application, get the worksheet, and then start iterating the used range.  When I try to get the value of the cell that contains the textbox, the value is null.

```
foreach (Range row in usedRange.Rows) {
    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])row.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
    var value = valueArray[1,10];  // This is null for textbox cells
}
```

Is there a special method I should use to get the value of the textbox that appears in an Excel worksheet?

**Edit with fix and explanation**

Stewbob's suggestion of iterating the shapes got me in the right direction.  But using the following code, I was getting null exceptions:

```
for (int i=1; i<shapes.Count;i++){
    var item = shapes.Range[i].Item(1);
    string myString = item.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text.ToString();
}
```

After looking at the object in Quickwatch, I noticed something odd about the shape.  It was of type msoOLEControlObject.  It turns out the values on this Excel document are cut and pasted into Excel from a webpage.  Excel was not creating textboxes but OLE boxes.  The OLE box did have a 'Value' property so I could access the textboxes value as such:

```
var shapes = ws.Shapes;
    for (int i=1; i<shapes.Count;i++){
        var item = shapes.Range[i].Item(1);
        var myText = item.OLEFormat.Object;
        if (myText.Object != null) {
            if (myText.Object.Value != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(myText.Object.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

So make sure if you are dealing with pasted objects that you check the value property and not the TextRange property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the name of the Text Box, you can reference it this way:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).Select
```

If you don't know the name, you can use `ActiveSheet.Shapes` to iterate through all the shapes on the worksheet.

Getting to the actual text in the TextBox is not very straightforward in VBA.  The following code iterates through all the `Shape` objects on the active worksheet:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Dim myText As String

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    myText = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
Next
```

Though I see that you are working in C#, so the above code will be a little different, but it at least gives you the object model to get to the text inside the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the TextBox isn't actually inside any cell (although it may appear to be).

Instead, you have to get it from the Shapes collection in the WorkSheet.